# How to achieve this layout?

Tags: html, css, gwt, uibinder

I want to basically create this kind of layout:

[image: Login Panel]

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should more clearly state that you require UiBinder GWT-specific solution, not simple html markup.

Comment: I mean, tags are your only tips here. No surprise answerers are unhappy.

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML:

```
<div id="login">
    <div class="float_left">
      Your input here <br/>
       Your remember me checkbox and text
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
      Your second input here <br/>
      And then your forget password link
    </div>
    <div class="float_left">
      Login button here
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;"/>
</div>
```

Your CSS:

```
#login {}
.float_left {float:left;}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider that the 'best' way.

Comment: f$#@ this stupid question. I'm never answering noob html/css question again. Everyone got down voted even mine, the checked answer.

Comment: @rsplak | I'm guessing a snowball of downvotes after someone lost their temper on a silly q/a website that we all love.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, but I do think enclosing the whole form in a div, using brs instead of proper styling and naming a class "float_left" are kind of suboptimal, from a code style standpoint.

Comment: well the question is totally noob material but how would you do it?

Comment: @Sam: I put an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383653/how-to-achieve-this-layout/5385910#5385910  — The CSS is a little bit longer, but the form itself is shorter and doesn't rely so much on the styling. I don't mean to knock you — I just figured the downvoter might be reacting a little harshly to those things, so it seemed worth explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the semantically clean way to do it:

#### The HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="username" placeholder="user name">
    <label><input id="rememberme" type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
    <a href="forgotpassword.html">Forgot your password?</a>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

#### The CSS:

```
fieldset { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#username, #password {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or something like that. I would use labels instead of placeholders, but there weren't any labels in your mockup, so I didn't want to add extra elements.

Answer (score 2):

The "best way" would be to use either [flexible box model](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/) (`display: box`, if you have some specific sizes to give to the blocks so they'll align) or table layout (`display: table`). Unfortunately, Internet Explorer 6 and 7 have absolutely [no support for any of them](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).
So I'd go with either (as this question is GWT-oriented):

- a plain old `<table>` in an `HTMLPanel` (and use `role=presentation` for best accessibility)
- `FlexTable` or `Grid` widget (which are backed by a `table`)

Answer (score 1):

Look, I've turned Sam's answer above into UI:Binder template. (Errors are possible, I'm writing XML here by hand.)

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
  <ui:style>
    .float_left {float:left;}
  </ui:style>

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel class='{style.float_left}'>
      <g:TextBox ui:field='loginTextBox'/>
      <br/>
      <g:CheckBox ui:field='rememberMeCheckBox'>Remember me</g:CheckBox>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel class='{style.float_left}'>
      <g:PasswordTextBox ui:field='passwordTextBox'/>
      <br/>
      <g:Hyperlink ui:field='passwordRestorationHyperlink'>Forgot your password?</g:Hyperlink>
    </g:FlowPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel class='{style.float_left}'>
      <g:Button ui:field='loginButton' text='Login'>Login</g:Button>
    </g:FlowPanel>
    <br style="clear:both;"/>
  </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And the corresponding Java class. That should go with no surprise - `@UiField` and `uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)` are your friends there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may sound bad, but I think tables is the best way to go in this case:

```
<table style="border: none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="login" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="password" type="password" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="keepMeLogged">
      <label for="keepMeLogged">Keep me logged in</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="forgot.php">Forgot your password?</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It seems Facebook uses this approach too.

Answer (score -1):

### CSS

```
input[type=text] { width: 200px; }
span.keep { display: inline-block; width: 200px; }
```

### HTML

```
<input type="text" /> <input type="text" /> <button>Login</button> <br />
<span class="keep"><input type="checkbox" />Keep me logged in</span>
<a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
```

### See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/foghina/92E2a/